A book I read around 25 years ago including a salt sea that blinds people, "gods" including two called Ari and Paty
I know it's a long shot, but I'm trying to find a book I read about 25 years ago, checked out from a public library in California. Here is was I can remember of it:
Book details: Likely a YA fantasy or mythological fiction, possibly from the late 1990s.
Setting/unique elements: Includes a salt sea that blinds people. It also causes salt crystals to grow in their eyes, I think?.
Story: In the very beginning, a male character named Beau is chosen for his beauty and turned into a statue while performing a lascivious act. The female protagonist accompanies him and later interacts with gods, who are revealed not to be gods at all (plot twist). She is the main character but, to my frustration, I can’t remember her name.
Key characters that I can recall the names of:
Beau: Chosen for his beauty; turned into a statue.
Ari: A male god who flies around the protagonist's room in fits.
Paty: Another male god, short for “Patience,” who was Ari's lover; their relationship hints at coercion.
The “gods” are all named after virtues (ex Patience).
Themes: Gods, transformations, beauty, and deception regarding divinity.
Another detail that I honestly can’t remember if I’m even remembering correctly was something along the lines of a cat-like race, I think the gods might have been this race.

Humility Garden by Felicity Savage
Description from Goodreads:

Her destiny was among the gods. In the land of Salt, the gods have
ruled among the humans for centuries. Now a new movement has taken
grip, denying the gods are masters and thrusting the world into chaos.
Young Humility Garden's only dream is to escape her squalid homeland.
But the prophets envision a future that holds much more. She is about
to embark on a journey that will teach her the secretive ways of the
ghostiers, the language of the gods, and the power of eternal love.
Amid countless enemies, in a wondrous realm of divine beauty and
ruthless politics, Humility discovers that her fate and the fate of
Salt are inextricably intertwined, and that together they may rise to
new heights - or fall into the bitterest depths...


From one of the reviews: "Humility Gardens betrothed Beau is being taken away to the decaden capital city to be an eternal ghost(no idea) on account of his great beauty,and Humi asks if she can come with him so they go with Godsbrother Sensuality." Great find! How did you find it? I was searching for this one today for ages.

I had found it previously for a search on Goodreads group "What's the name of that book" and I remembered Beau, I used the search function in the group and the topic came up.
